# How to Click on filename on my PHP web page to play video on HTML5 video player?

Tags: javascript, php, html, video, href

I am a (self-learning) beginner. 
I have PHP code on one page (page 1) to display a list of video files available on the server.

```
foreach ($filelist1 as $file2)
{
    echo "<a href='???'>". $file2."</a><br>";
}
```

I have another page (page 2) that has the video player.

```
<video id="videoPlayer" width="75%" height="75%" preload controls= "controls" tabindex="0" poster="/videolibrary/2.jpg">
        <source id='mp4Source' src="/videolibrary/<?php echo $usr; ?>/1.webm" type="video/mp4" />
        <source id='oggSource' src="/videolibrary/<?php echo $usr; ?>/1.webm" type="video/ogg" />
        <source id='webmSource' src="/videolibrary/<?php echo $usr; ?>/1.webm" type="video/webm" />
```

Page 1 is embedded in Page 2 as an IFRAME. My question is, when I click on the filename there on Page 1, I want the video player on Page 2 to play that video. 
Could you please explain how to achieve this?
That would be most helpful to many beginners.

Comment: I would rather put page 2 in an iFrame on page 1 and then post the link to page 2 via URL and then use GET on page2, loading it in the iframe.

Comment: I am a beginner. Could you please post edits to the code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is this is how I would do it.

Code for **page1.php**:

```
<html>
<body>
<h5>Video List: </h5>
    <ul>
        <?php 
            $filelist = scandir("videolibrary");
            foreach($filelist as $key=>$video){
                if($key >1){
                    echo '<li><a href="#" onclick="parent.document.querySelector(\'#myVideo > source\').src = \''. $video. '\'">'.$video.'</a></li>';
                }
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
</br>
</body>
</html>
```

Code for **page2.php**:

```
<html>
<body>

<center>
    <video id="MyVideo" width="720" height="480" controls>
        <source src="" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</center>
<iframe src="page1.php" name="viframe" id="viframe" width="80%" height="60%">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**Requirement**:
For the above codes to work, create a folder named "*videolibrary*" in the same directory as page1.php and page2.php

Test:
Open page2.php, you should get a list of video files found under the *videolibrary* directory in the iFrame which is displayed by page1.php. Clicking on one of them will load it in the iFrame via javascript.

Comment: Page 1 is embedded in Page 2 as an IFRAME. When I click on the link, the vname attribute is passed. However, PAGE 2 is opened again inside the iframe. So, the result is two  Page 2's on the same page. How to solve that? Thanks.

Comment: Do see my first comment to your original question. I did suggest to have page1 containing page2 within an iFrame. So the codes I gave above are for that setting as agreed. Is it a must that page2 needs to contain page1? If yes, then there are a few changes to be made to the structure.